# Arduino IDE changes Com Port from 3 to 5 - why?

Tags: windows-10, ide, arduino, com-port

Have Arduino IDE 1.8.1 set up on Com Port 3.  Works fine with Adafruit Uno board. Plug in another Adafruit Uno Arduino board, that does not work properly, and IDE changes Com Port 3 to Com Port 5. Why, how do I change it back, and how do I stop it from changing Com Ports?  Don't know what's wrong with 2nd board, but can't trouble shoot it with wrong Com Port.  Arduino IDE 1.8.1 and Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

The Arduino is read as different by the computer. This is normal and sometimes the same Arduino board is read as a different com Port. Hope this helps...